# Is iteration over LinkedHashSet faster than iteration over ArrayList

Tags: java, big-o

I want to iterate over 2 collections each one roughly 600 records. I want to compare each element of collection one with all other elements in collection two. If I choose my collection to be LinkedHashSet then, I have to call iterator on each collection and have two while (inner and outer) loop.
And for the choice of ArrayList, I will have two for loops (inner and outer) to read data from each collection.

Primarily I chose LinkedHashSet because I read that LinkedHashSet has a better performance, I also preferred using set to remove duplicate, but after seeing it running very slow, taking around 2 hours to finish, I thought maybe It would be better to copy set into an ArrayList and then iterate over ArrayList instead of LinkedHashSet.
I was wondering which one would have a better choice to speed up the runtime.

public ArrayList> processDataSourcesV2(LinkedHashMap> ppmsFinalResult,LinkedHashMap> productDBFinalResult ) {
      //each parameter is a hashmap that contains key(id) and value (set of unique parameters)
      ArrayList> result = new ArrayList>();

```
  Iterator<Entry<RecordId, LinkedHashSet<String>>> ppmsIterator = ppmsFinalResult.entrySet().iterator();
  Iterator<Entry<RecordId, LinkedHashSet<String>>> productIdIterator =null;
  //pair of id from each list
  ArrayList<Pair> listOfIdPair = new ArrayList<Pair>();
  while (ppmsIterator.hasNext()) {
      //RecordId object is an object containing the id and which list this id belongs to
      Entry<RecordId, LinkedHashSet<String>> currentPpmsPair = ppmsIterator.next();
      RecordId currentPpmsIDObj = currentPpmsPair.getKey(); 
      //set of unique string
      LinkedHashSet<String> currentPpmsCleanedTerms = (LinkedHashSet<String>)currentPpmsPair.getValue();
      productIdIterator = productDBFinalResult.entrySet().iterator();

      while (productIdIterator.hasNext()) {

          Entry<RecordId, LinkedHashSet<String>> currentProductDBPair = productIdIterator.next();
          RecordId currentProductIDObj = currentProductDBPair.getKey();
          LinkedHashSet<String> currentProductCleanedTerms = (LinkedHashSet<String>)currentProductDBPair.getValue();
          ArrayList<Object> listOfRowByRowProcess = new ArrayList <Object>();
          Pair currentIDPair = new Pair(currentPpmsIDObj.getIdValue(),currentProductIDObj.getIdValue());              
          //check for duplicates 
          if ((currentPpmsIDObj.getIdValue()).equals(currentProductIDObj.getIdValue()) || listOfIdPair.contains(currentIDPair.reverse()) ) {
              continue;
          }
          else {
              LinkedHashSet<String> commonTerms = getCommonTerms(currentPpmsCleanedTerms,currentProductCleanedTerms);
              listOfIdPair.add(currentIDPair.reverse());
              if (commonTerms.size()>0) {
                  listOfRowByRowProcess.add(currentPpmsIDObj);
                  listOfRowByRowProcess.add(currentProductIDObj);
                  listOfRowByRowProcess.add(commonTerms);

                  result.add(listOfRowByRowProcess); 
              }
          }

      }


  }

  return result;
}



 public LinkedHashSet<String> getCommonTerms(LinkedHashSet<String> setOne, LinkedHashSet<String> setTwo){
     Iterator<String> setOneIt = setOne.iterator();
     LinkedHashSet<String> setOfCommon = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
     //making hard copy
     while (setOneIt.hasNext()) {
         setOfCommon.add(setOneIt.next());
     }
     setOfCommon.retainAll(setTwo);
     return setOfCommon;
 }
```

Comment: FIrst of all, you will not see any performance difference between the two unless you are up to billions of comparisons.  Second, if you build the sets based on the properties you want to compare you do not have to do a nested loop.  Your question is extremely unclear, so you should show the class definitions of the objects you want to work with and explain what you mean by "compare".  Then show what code you have already written.

Comment: Do you just want to find all elements of collection 1 that are **also** in collection 2? Or perhaps all elements of collection 1 that are **not** in collection 2?

Comment: @Bohemian: Yes that is right

Comment: @user1836957 which one is it then: when they're in both or when they're in only one?

Comment: @Bohemian, I want to find all elements of collection 1 that are also in collection 2

Comment: @JimGarrison: I attached the code that I have tried, but it is very slow and I am looking for a way to improve it

Comment: Read @Bohemian's answer

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are faster than any other structure when it comes to iteration (all elements are stored sequentially in memory ), one the other hand, it slower when deleting and inserting  element because it has to ensure the sequential storage. Iterating over linked list is slower because you might get page fault...  So it's up to you which one to choose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find which elements are in both collections, make one a `Set` and get its *intersection* with the other collection:

```
Collection<T> collection1, collection2; // given these

Set<T> intersection = new HashSet<T>(collection1);
intersection.retainAll(collection2);
```

This will execute in O(n) time, where `n` is the size of `collection2`, because finding elements in a `HashSet` performs in constant time.

My guess is you are checking every element of `collection1` with every element of `collection2`, which has O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity.